# not getting select value by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get the value from select in my jquery.

```
        <tr>
                    <td><label for="T_sender">Sender Code<span class="required_field">*</span></label></td>
                    <td><select id="T_sender" name="T_sender">
                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                            <?php if(isset($Tsender)) : foreach($Tsender as $send) : ?>
                            <?php echo "<option value=".$send->add_id.">".$send->add_name.",&nbsp;".$send->add_line1."</option>"; ?>    
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php else : ?> 
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </select> 
                    </td>
    </tr>
```

In my jquery i tried the code,

```
$("#T_sender").change(function(){   
var x = $('#T_sender').val();
alert(x); });
```

But i don't get any alert. Somebody please help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: add your script in a dom ready handler

Comment: also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: like `jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#T_sender").change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();
        alert(x);
    });
})`

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/rkZqc/

Comment: Note that within the `change` handler it is more efficient to use `$(this).val()` rather than reselecting the element by id, and even more efficient to use `this.value`.

Comment: whether the `select` element is create dynamically after the dom ready event

Comment: can you add a `alert($("#T_sender").length)` before `$("#T_sender").change(...);` and tell us what is alerted

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#T_sender").change(function(){   
        var x = $(this).val();
        alert(x); 
    });
})
```

Comment: still not getting.
i think the change function is not executing onchange of T_sender.
What could be the possible errors??

Comment: does it alert blank value